# Return Holiday Reference (type)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of holiday dates that goes from 1990 to 2110 for different countries. Is there a way in excel to get the holiday type for that specific date?

Let's take one as example. Mexico, 15/11/2021 which is Monday and it's the Revolution Day. Is there any way to get excel to spit out that "Revolution Day" based on the date?

Cheers all!

(even vba solution accepted)

Comment: Do you have the day names in the data?

Answer (score 0):

Make a column of dates in column A and then put their corresponding name in column B.  You could then use a VLOOKUP formula or a combination of INDEX and MATCH to return a name based on the date.

```
(A)         (B)             (C)            (D)
Date        Holiday Name    15/11/2011     =vlookup(C1,$A$1:$B$4,2,0)
15/11/2021  Revolution Day
25/11/2018  Christmas Day
1/1/2028    New Years Day
```

Comment: Now making a table of all the holidays is a pretty extensive list, but it will work since each date is unique.  Which mean you need to enter annual holidays for each year in this approach.  You can also put each country's holiday in a separate column.  You change the 2 in lookup to suit what country you are dealing with is an option as well.

Comment: A potentially better approach would be to check the date against a criteria but then you wind up with a lot of if then  statements.  ie. `=If(and(month(C1)=11, Day(c1)=15, "Revolution Day","")`  In VBA you can have unlimited If statements so you can check for a lot of holidays.  in Excel formulas though you have a limited number of IF statements in a single cell.  You can get around that limit but you would need to use helper cells